# How to inherit Entity Framework configuration classes (with collections)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, configuration, ef-code-first

We are using Entity Framework 6 to form our DAL. For a certain part of the application we try to reuse a large part of our “standard model”. We extend some of the classes (“Aaa” -> “AaaSp”)  there for use in a new model and adding associations to them. (See picture). The classes defined in Special together with the classes referenced form “Aaa” are used to make a new DbContext (SpContext).
[image]
The problem is adding the configuration for the Bbb collection to the Aaa class.  In the SpecialDb we want to use “TablePerType”, so we don’t get the “TPH” with a useless discriminator. To configure this would like to inherit “ConfigAaa” in the config class of “AaaSp”.

Code Class "Aaa":

```
public class Aaa : Entity
{

    public IList<Bbb> Bbbs
    {
        get { return bbbs; }
        set { bbbs = value; }
    }
    private IList<Bbb> bbbs = new List<Bbb>();

    public class ConfigAaa:EntityConfigurationBase<T>

    {
        public ConfigAaa()
        {
            HasMany(a => a.Bbbs).WithMany(b => b.Aaas);
        }
    }
}
```

To do this “ConfigAaa” needs to be generic like “EntityConfigurationBase” is. We tried something like this:

```
public class Aaa : Entity
{

    public IList<Bbb> Bbbs
    {
        get { return bbbs; }
        set { bbbs = value; }
    }
    private IList<Bbb> bbbs = new List<Bbb>();

    public class ConfigAaa<T>:EntityConfigurationBase<T> where T: Aaa

    {
        public ConfigAaa()
        {
            HasMany(a => a.Bbbs).WithMany(b => b.Aaas);
            //Error:  collection Aaas is not of Type T                  
        }
    }
}
```

However as soon as we do so, we get an error on collection properties of “Aaa”.Cannot convert expression type ‘System.Collections.Generic.IList’. Although the “where “ constraint limits the “T” to an “Aaa” or descendant.

Is there a way to make this work?